# Materialize navbar links conditional rendering

Tags: css, reactjs, navbar, materialize

I am using React Materialize and React Router Dom. I'm trying to show navlinks to only authenticated users, so I'm using conditional rendering. But if I do it like below, navlinks are rendered vertical, not horizontal as usual. Is there a solution for that? Thanks

```
    <Navbar>
      {isAuthenticated && (
      <>
      <NavLink to="/locations" href="/locations">
        Locations
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink to="/categories" href="/categories">
        Categories
      </NavLink>
      </>
      )}
    </Navbar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `Navbar` component is rendering all of its children inside `li` elements. When you wrap them in a fragment, the component considers this as its only child element and puts all of the `NavLink` elements in a single `li`.

I can think of two simple approaches to handle this:

1. If there are only a few links, you can do conditional rendering for them:

```
<Navbar>
 {isAuthenticated && (<NavLink to="/locations" href="/locations">Locations</NavLink>)}
 {isAuthenticated && (<NavLink to="/categories" href="/categories">Categories</NavLink>)}
</Navbar>
```

However, this solution is not reliable, especially if you have a lot of links.

2. Store the `NavLink` elements in some array and conditionally add the auth-dependant items:

```
// In the component:
const links = [/* some public links */];
const privateLinks = [
    // Don't forget keys. The numbers here are only for example.
    <NavLink key={1} to="/locations" href="/locations">Locations</NavLink>,
    <NavLink key={2} to="/categories" href="/categories">Categories</NavLink>
];

if(isAuthenticated){
 links.push(...privateLinks);
}
```

```
// In the template:
<Navbar>{links}</Navbar>
```

The logic with the links arrays is pretty trivial (with setting private links as the last items) only to keep the demo more simple.

Comment: I tried the 2. solution and it worked perfectly, thank you very much. :)